# Java SWT/JFace TreeViewer move nodes by drag/drop in view

Tags: eclipse, treeview, swt, jface

I am using a TreeViewer for displaying my tree. I would like to offer the opportunity to sort nodes by hand by letting the user drag a node and let him drop it at the new location.

I am looking for a possiblity for determining between which nodes the node was dropped or whether it was drop at the control-border and the first node.
Is there any suggest or usual way for detecting the drop location relative to the other nodes(before/after)?

My idea was to get the Point of the drop look whichh node is there an whether the point is in the upper or lower half of the items-boundary (sounds easy, but is sure painfully to implement). I would appreciate any other possibility...

Comment: Could you post your code and indicate where the pain is? :)

Comment: I have no code yet, just the idea of having to do it like described above causes me pain ;-). So that is the usual way to do it? Do you know some example implementation? Can't believe I am the first one needing this feature?

Answer (score 2):

Detecting the item based on cursor location is pretty much the only way and you probably need to do this also during `dragOver()`. [Here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/SWT-JFace-Eclipse/DragandDropexamplesnippetdragleafitemsinatree.htm)'s an example.